# how to pass an argument from a button?

Tags: javascript, html, function, arguments

I'am trying to make a dynamic function which can take an arguments from the user input and making a simple mathematics operation... and i always get a Reference Error.

i will show you my code and i hope you can understand what i'am aiming for

thanks in advance <3

```js
/* global window*/

function generate(start, end) {
    "use strict";
    
    start = window.myInput.value;
    end = window.myOutput.value;
    
    var years;
    
    for (years = start; years <= end; years += 1) {
        window.mySelect.innerHTML += '<option>' + years + '</option>';
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="myInput">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="myOutput">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button onclick="generate()">Generate!</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="mySelect">
                        <option selected>your Years</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
```

PS: I'am trying to add options from the inserted start year to the inserted end year in the .

Answer (score 1):

Now you can get the gradation of the specified years. Was it so necessary for you?

```js
let myInput = document.querySelector('#myInput');
let myOutput = document.querySelector('#myOutput');
let mySelect = document.querySelector('#mySelect');

function generate() {
    "use strict";
    
    let start = myInput.value;
    let end = myOutput.value;
    
    var years;
    
    for (years = start; years <= end; years++) {
        window.mySelect.innerHTML += '<option>' + years + '</option>';
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
   
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="myInput">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="myOutput">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button onclick="generate()">Generate!</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="mySelect">
                        <option selected>your Years</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
  
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/* global window*/

function generate(start, end) {
    "use strict";
    
    start = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    end = document.getElementById("myOutput").value;
    mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    
    var years;
    
    for (years = start; years <= end; years += 1) {
        mySelect.innerHTML += '<option>' + years + '</option>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Here is a simple and easy-to-understand way of doing this:

```js
const generate = () => {
  let start = document.querySelector('#myInput').value
  const end = document.querySelector('#myOutput').value
  const years = document.querySelector('#mySelect')

  while (start <= end) {
    years.innerHTML += `<option>${start}</option>`
    start++
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="myInput">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="myOutput">
      </td>
      <td>
        <button onclick="generate()">Generate!</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select id="mySelect">
          <option selected>your Years</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

As this does work fine (with a small numbers of iterations), we could enter as many years as we wanted, so this could create a ton of DOM elements in this loop using:

```js
years.innerHTML += `<option>${start}</option>`
```

This is really easy to read and understand, but this isn't the best for performance. One way we can solve this performance issue is by using `createElement`/`appendChild` like this:

```js
const generate = () => {
  let start = document.querySelector('#myInput').value
  const end = document.querySelector('#myOutput').value
  const years = document.querySelector('#mySelect')

  while (start <= end) {
    const newOption = document.createElement('option') // Create option node
    newOption.innerText = start // Set option node text

    years.appendChild(newOption) // Append option node to select element
    start++
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="myInput">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="myOutput">
      </td>
      <td>
        <button onclick="generate()">Generate!</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select id="mySelect">
          <option selected>your Years</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Now you can see the difference in performance between both of these snippets by making them both start at `1` and end at `2000` (`1999` iterations).

You will see the first snippet (`innerHTML`) once you hit the generate button. The whole page will be inactive for a few seconds. This is because the script is taking so long to run. While in the second snippet we don't have any inactivity (`createElement`/`appendChild`).